# Connecting Button To App Deligate Not Working Xcode AppleScript

Tags: applescript, xcode

I have just Installed Xcode Version 13.4.1 and trying to follow some online tutorials for Creating and AppleScript project.
I have started by adding a simple button to the Window.

In AppDelegate.applescript under the IBOutlets I have enteed this code.

```
on btnGo_(sender)
  display dialog "hello!"    
end btnGo_
```

Back in **MainMenu.xib** I control and drag from the button onto the App Deligate Cube Icon to connect the button to the above code but I am Not seeing it in the list.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong here ?

Comment: It looks like the [Xcode 13 bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69446889/10853463) is still not fixed.

Comment: Unbelieable, I am more green than a Novice when it comes to Xcode. I have spent hours trying to work out why this is not working and you says its a Bug :-(

Do we know if version 14 Beta has fixed this issue